# Moving an armature over [-pi,+pi] radians

Tags: python, rigging, game-engine, armature

I am working with robots, ROS and MORSE simulator. And I have a problem when I tried to control a robot simulated in MORSE using ROS. As MORSE is based on BGE, I am asking here my question.

My robot is able to move a joint from -0.78 to +4 radians using ROS and MoveIt!, something quite common with robots. But, the movement of the joint is stuck to (+pi) in Blender. For my understanding the joint maximum range of a blender armature  is [-pi,+pi] and this is the reason that the joint of my robot gets stuck. You could read the full story of what I am doing [here](https://github.com/morse-simulator/morse/issues/547).

Could I fix this issue in some way? I cannot set more than [-pi,+pi] in Blender for the inverse kinematics information, is my understanding correct? I am only interested on the direct kinematics as all the inverse kinematics and control it is done outside Blender by ROS.

I was looking for information about this topic in Internet but I was not able to find anything useful.

So, I am trying to set manually the position of an armature joint to an specific position, that's creating an algorithm that converts the position sent using ROS [-0.78,+4 ] to the expected joint position of the armature [-pi,+pi]. However, the joint does the complete turn, +pi,..0,..-pi, when I set (-pi+0.1) as next position when the joint is in (+pi) position.

If my explanation is not clear enough let me know and I will add more details. Thanks.